# Excel Sendkeys - How to prevent Excel from getting focus back when VBA sends keys?

Tags: excel, sendkeys, vba

The code below do not work as expected:

```
Sub CopyDataFromAppThenBackToExcel()

    SendKeys "%{TAB}"  'Send Alt+TAB
    SendKeys ("%es")   'Send Alt then "E" then "S"
    SendKeys ("%ec")   'Send Alt then "E" then "C"
    SendKeys "%{TAB}"  
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

When I click an button located in my Excel Worksheet, this code is executed. It is supposed to bring an app to focus (Alt+Tab), then select all data in the app (Alt E S), copy all selected data (Alt E C), then go back to Excel (Alt+Tab) and paste the clipboard to cell A1. But Excel pastes the "old" clipboard content, it do not copy the content of the app. I tried to sleep 500 miliseconds between each line of code but nothing changed (`Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr`)).

It seems that, for each SendKeys line, Excel brings automatically the focus back to the worksheet. How do I prevent it from happening, so that the focus keep on the other app until the second Alt+Tab line is executed?

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not possible**

Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-sendkeys-method-excel the sendkeys method only submits the keystrokes to the key buffer of the active application, Excel in this case, not the OS.

Comment: @strajano consolidation seems to be wishful thinking all too often haha